# Ayuda con error en creacion de tablas SQLITE3

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

tengo un error con el siguiente query de mi tabla en sqlite3:

```
Create table EmpleadosCursos(
Empleado constraint fk1_empleadoscursos references empleados,
Curso constraint fk2_empleadoscursos references cursos,
constraint pk_empleadoscursos primary key(empleado,curso),
fecha date);
```

El error:

> Error : near "fecha": syntax error

Comment: El error es : Error : near "fecha": syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que sqlite no tiene el tipo de datos **Date**, sino que sólo los siguientes:

> INTEGER, TEXT, BLOB, REAL y NUMERIC.